# Is there any way to customize the UNnotification for local notifications in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification

I am new to Xcode and swift. I want to know that is there any way that we can customize the local notifications. If possible I also want to add a map on the notification.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a target from **File** -> **New** -> **Target** -> **Notification Content Extension**
which will add an extension for your custom UI. Set the `UNNotificationExtensionCategory` to the string identifier.

If you want to add a map on the notification , add a Mapkit View  into storyboard in the extension. I have attached the code for the map:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension{
    
  //  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel?
   fileprivate let locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       // mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    }
    
    func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
        //self.label?.text = notification.request.content.body
     
        self.label?.text = "Reminder for your charging "
    }
    
    @IBAction func notibutton(_ sender: Any) {
        
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
I tried using the notification extension identifier  and called in the function in the app delegate of the main target 
It worked for me also the map is displayed in the notification.